# Compatibility issue between IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web

I have a CSS which will display the content only with vertical scroll bar and not the Horizontal scroll bar.

My CSS is,

```
div.rightSide {
display: inline;
float: right;
height: 234px;
margin: 5px 0;
overflow-y: auto;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
visibility: inherit;
width: 300px;
z-index: 6;
}
```

It works as expected in IE8 and Mozilla 3.6, but when I test the same in IE7, vertical scroll bar is also getting displayed. So what should i want to do in order to overcome this issue?

**EDIT**

Adding my HTML code.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="contentColumn">
            <div class="overviewPage">
                <div class="instructionContent" id="sample_id">
                    <div class="overviewBackground" style="z-index: 3;">
                        <p class="sidebar_body">
                            <img align="center" border="0" height="244"
                                src="../images/product/sample.jpg" width="752" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightSide">
                        <div class="unitOverview">
                            <p class="body">
                                <span class="bold">Unit 1 Overview</span>
                            </p>
                            <div class="sectionContents">
                                <div class="subhead_pri"> 
                                <!-- My title goes here -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="sectionBody" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%">
                                    <p class="body"> 
                                    <!-- My content Goes here -->
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vendor">ID: vendor1</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks,
Jeya

Comment: Can you put html code? because I have answer depends on html code, just for that div you use with class "rightSide" and its container, and if you put css for container will be better.

Comment: Have added my HTML code also.

Comment: thank you, but is that div with class called "instructionContent" has a width in CSS?

Comment: Waiting you :) , if you can put "instructionContent" style, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your css as well.

Comment: I have added the above snippet, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with your content. overflow-y:auto means 'only show a vertical scrollbar if you have to.' Apparently IE7 thinks your content is tall enough that it needs the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

By default IE7 treats your container as if it had `overflow: auto`.
You need to tell it otherwise.
try adding `overflow: hidden` **before** `overflow-y: auto`, helped in my case.